# Using TensorFlow 1.15 and tflearn 1.19 but this code is not working

Tags: tensorflow, cpu, python-3.7, tflearn, tensorflow1.15

```
    import nltk
    from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
    stemmer = LancasterStemmer()
    import numpy
    import tflearn
    import tensorflow
    import random
    import json
    with open("intents.json") as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    wrds = []
    labels = []
    docs_x = []
    docs_y = []

    for intent in data["intents"]:
        for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
            wrds = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
            wrds.extend(wrds)
            docs_x.append(pattern)
            docs_y.append(intent["tag"])

        if intent["tag"] not in labels:
            labels.append(intent["tag"])
```

Please tell me why this code isn't running its giving this errors:

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\summarizer.py:9: The name tf.summary.merge is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.summary.merge instead

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py:25: The name tf.summary.FileWriter is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter instead

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tflearn\collections.py:13: The name tf.GraphKeys is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys instead

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py:123: The name tf.get_collection is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_collection instead

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py:129: The name tf.add_to_collection is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.add_to_collection instead

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py:131: The name tf.assign is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.assign instead.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Those are warnings and shouldn't really be halting your script.  Are there any other errors?  Is there a full traceback?

Comment: ill just check that thanks for responding though